# How change hostpython for use python3 on MacOS for compile Python+Kivy project for Xcode

Tags: python, xcode, macos, kivy

I use toolchain from Kivy for compile Python + Kivy project on MacOS, but by default, toolchain use python2 recipes but I need change to python3.

I´m googling but I don't find how I can do this.

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: I´ve used `toolchain.py clean python2` , `toolchain.py clean hostpython2` and `toolchain.py clean hostpython` command and then I ran `toolchain.py build hostpython3 kivy` and the command gave this error: `ERROR: Wanted to use hostpython3 ERROR: but hostpython is already provided by hostpython2  ERROR: You can only one hostpython version compiled`. How is possible if I clean three of them toolchain tell me this ERROR?

Comment: I've found that trying to clean the python/hostpython recipes still won't let you install a different python/hostpython. If you go and re-download kivy-ios from the github page, you should be able to build python3.

Comment: I'm reinstall kivy using this command `pip install https://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/master.zip` and then I try to `toolchain.py  build python3 kivy` and give me the same ERROR

Comment: your kivy installation is likely fine already. Your kivy-ios installation is not. Completely remove your `kivy-ios` folder on your computer, then do `git clone git://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios` to reinstall kivy-ios. Then try using `toolchain.py` to build python3 instead of python 2

Comment: Great. Works!!!! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your kivy installation is likely fine already. Your kivy-ios installation is not. Completely remove your `kivy-ios` folder on your computer, then do `git clone git://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios` to reinstall kivy-ios. Then try using `toolchain.py` to build python3 instead of python 2

This solution work for me. Thanks very much Erik.

Answer (score 0):

For example, recipe "ios" and "pyobjc" dependency is changed from `depends = ["python"]` to `depends = ["python3"]`. (`__init__.py` in each packages in receipe folder in kivy-ios package)

These recipes are loaded from your request implicitly or explicitly

This description of the problem recipes is equal to require hostpython2/python2. then conflict with python3.

The dependency of each recipe can be traced from output of kivy-ios. "hostpython" or "python" in output(console) were equaled to hostpython2 or python2.(now ver.)